# Error inflating GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to set my GLSurfaceView on an xml layout along with other UI elements and keep getting error inflating class com.vi.cubo01.MyGLSurfaceView in the LogCat.

Here is the java code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           mGLSurfaceView = (MyGLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.vistaGLSuperficie)
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);            
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {

            super.onResume();
            mGLSurfaceView = (MyGLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.vistaGLSuperficie);
            mGLSurfaceView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
            super.onPause();
            mGLSurfaceView = (MyGLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.vistaGLSuperficie);
            mGLSurfaceView.onPause();
    }



    class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
        public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
            setRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
        }
    }
```

and the xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<com.vi.cubo01.MyGLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/vistaGLSuperficie"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are inflating from XML, you will need to include the (Context, AttributeSet) constructor in addition to the (Context) constructor that you already have. This is because that is the one that the layout inflator needs to call in order to process the attributes you have specified in the XML, e.g. layout_width and layout_height.

```
public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
}
```

Comment: From the code you've posted, it's not clear if MyGLSurfaceView is defined inside your Activity class or not - make sure you have it defined outside of it. Also in your onCreate(), make sure you only use findViewById after calling setContentView, not before, or you'll get null.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved as soon as I removed MyGLSurfaceView from the main activity.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version:

```
class MyGLSurfaceView(context: Context,
                          attributes: AttributeSet? = null): GLSurfaceView(context, attributes) {
// ...
}
```